# access vba get cyrillic text from ini file into database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ini

2012/08/31 : Updated my Post

searched all the web for it, found pieces but nothing really helped so i turn to you.

---

Information about environment:

Programming language is VBA / Access 2003

Data will be read from existing ".ini" File

Data should be inserted into Access Database

---

Now to my Problem:

I've got a ini file with information inside an ini file. The file looks something like this:

```
[product_details]
product_description=my product description
product_name=my product
product_price=11.0
product_sku=myproduct2012
```

these information are saved into "products.ini", when open in notepad or notepad++ it will be displayed correct and can be inserted into my access database and i can display these information in my form

but now someone wants to have something like this:

```
[product_details]
product_description=мое описание продукта
product_name=мой продукт
product_price=11.0
product_sku=произведение2012
```

when loading these information via GetINIValue the Value will be saved into Database as unreadable text.

edit: also in Notepad / Notepad++ it is displayed correct, so the cyrillic chars are transferred correct into the ini-file

I really tried many things (using UNICODE Version of GetINIValue, get Code of Char etc., check if Cyrillic text) nothing helped.

What it should do:
I need help to get the Value from this ini entry no matter what language (in this case, English, German, french, Russian are just enough)

Hope someone could help me.

Edit: I've tried Remou's Testing with this Peace of Code open it up by following:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim strValue As String
strValue = GetValueOf("product_details","product_description","C:\cyrillic.txt")
SQL = "UPDATE [products] SET [product_description]='" & strValue & "' WHERE [product_id]=23;"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL,dbseechanges
```

Heres the Code of my Function to read out the Specific Line i need:

```
Public Function GetValueOf(ByVal Section As String, ByVal Entry As String, ByVal File As String)
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim temp As String
Dim response As String
Dim intresponses As String
Dim SectionFoundBegin As Boolean
Dim SectionFoundEnd As Boolean
Dim DoNext As Boolean
Dim Parse() As String
Dim Finished As Boolean

SectionFoundBegin = False
SectionFoundEnd = False
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(File, ForReading, , TristateTrue)
response = ""
intresponses = 1
Finished = False

Do
  DoNext = False
  temp = ts.ReadLine

  If (Not Finished) Then
    If (temp = "[" & Section & "]") And Not DoNext Then
      SectionFoundBegin = True
      DoNext = True
    End If

  If ((InStr(1, temp, "[") > 0) And (SectionFoundBegin)) And Not DoNext Then
    SectionFoundEnd = True
    DoNext = True
  End If

  If (SectionFoundBegin And Not SectionFoundEnd) And Not DoNext Then
    If (InStr(1, temp, "=") > 0) Then
      Parse = Split(temp, "=")
      If (Parse(0) = Entry) Then
        While (intresponses <= UBound(Parse))
          response = response + Parse(intresponses)
          intresponses = intresponses + 1
        Wend

        DoNext = True
      Else
        DoNext = True
      End If
    Else
      DoNext = True
    End If
  End If

End If

Loop Until ts.AtEndOfStream
GetValueOf = response
End Function
```

What i need:
Something like:

```
"UPDATE [products] SET [product_description]='мое описание продукта' WHERE [product_id]=23;"
```

What i get:

```
"UPDATE [products] SET [product_description]='??? ???????? ????????' WHERE [product_id]=23;"
```

UPDATE:
Well now i really your help:

I've inserted the following Code:

```
 Public Function GetUnicodeValueOf(ByVal Section As String, ByVal Entry As String, ByVal File As String)
 Dim fs As Object
 Dim ts As Object
 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim temp As String
 Dim strResponse As String
 Dim intResponses As Integer
 Dim SectionFoundBegin As Boolean
 Dim SectionFoundEnd As Boolean
 Dim DoNext As Boolean
 Dim Parse() As String
 Dim Finished As Boolean

 On Error GoTo Error_GetUnicodeValueOf
 SectionFoundBegin = False
 SectionFoundEnd = False
 Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(File, ForReading, , TristateTrue)
 strResponse = ""
 intResponses = 1
 Finished = False

 Do
   DoNext = False
   temp = ts.ReadLine

   If (Not Finished) Then
     If (temp = "[" & Section & "]") And Not DoNext Then
       SectionFoundBegin = True
       DoNext = True
     End If

   If ((InStr(1, temp, "[") > 0) And (SectionFoundBegin)) And Not DoNext Then
     SectionFoundEnd = True
     DoNext = True
   End If

   If (SectionFoundBegin And Not SectionFoundEnd) And Not DoNext Then
     If (InStr(1, temp, "=") > 0) Then
       Parse = Split(temp, "=")
       If (Parse(0) = Entry) Then
         While (intResponses <= UBound(Parse))
           strResponse = strResponse + Parse(intResponses)
           intResponses = intResponses + 1
           Finished = True
         Wend

         DoNext = True
       Else
         DoNext = True
       End If
     Else
       DoNext = True
     End If
   End If

 End If

 Loop Until ts.AtEndOfStream

 Exit_GetUnicodeValueOf:
    GetUnicodeValueOf = strResponse
    Exit Function
 Error_GetUnicodeValueOf:
ActionLogging "Fehler beim Parsen der Datei '" & File & "'"
Resume Exit_GetUnicodeValueOf
 End Function
```

by using this file (saved as UTF-8 without BOM) on my Harddisc:

```
 [product_details]
 manufacturer_name=
 product_id=50
 sku=BU-01722
 set=4
 type=simple
 type_id=simple
 color=11
 ean=
 name=Колесникова
 description=[LANGTEXT] Колесникова Е.В Я считаю до двадцати [Рабочая тетрадь] 6-7л 
 short_description=[KURZTEXT] Колесникова Е.В
 old_id=
 weight=1.0000
 news_from_date=
 news_to_date=
 status=1
 url_key=kolesnikova
 url_path=kolesnikova.html
 visibility=4
 gift_message_available=2
 required_options=0
 has_options=0
 image_label=
 small_image_label=
 thumbnail_label=
 created_at=2012-06-25 07:58:29
 updated_at=2012-07-27 09:06:24
 price=2.0000
 special_price=
 special_from_date=
 special_to_date=
 cost=
 tax_class_id=2
 minimal_price=
 enable_googlecheckout=1
 meta_title=
 meta_keyword=
 meta_description=
 is_recurring=0
 recurring_profile=
 custom_design=
 custom_design_from=
 custom_design_to=
 custom_layout_update=
 page_layout=
 options_container=container2
```

and i need to have:

```
 [LANGTEXT] Колесникова Е.В Я считаю до двадцати [Рабочая тетрадь] 6-7л
```

from INI-Key: **description**

into my access database.

First it works as it should but now when i'm loading a file that is saved with "TriStateTrue" 
everything ends up in : ?????????????????????????????????????????????
in one line.

With TriStateMixed, everything is parsed well except of the cyrillic text which comes like
     ÐšÐ¾Ð»ÐµÑÐ½Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð° Ð•.Ð’    Ð¯ ÑÑ‡Ð¸Ñ‚Ð°ÑŽ Ð´Ð¾ Ð´Ð²Ð°Ð´Ñ†Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸ [Ð Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ‡Ð°Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÑ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð´ÑŒ] 6-7Ð»

i searched the sourcecode and didn't found the error.

```
 FILE is UTF-8 without BOM (coming from selfwritten Web API for Magento)
 Using Access 2003
 Need to get Cyrillic Text into my Database where also German / English Texts could be inside the File
```

Comment: How are you reading this? If I run `Dim fs As New FileSystemObject: Dim ts As TextStream: Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile("z:\docs\info.ini", ForReading, , TristateTrue): Screen.ActiveControl = ts.ReadAll` The text control on my sample form will contain exactly what you show. Note `TristateTrue`, which means open as unicode.
`

Comment: Can we suppose that the .ini file is saved as an UTF-8 or UNICODE text file on the file system and not as an ASCII one? ("Encoding" field in Save as dialog ...)

Comment: Thanks for you Answers, will test your Solution @Remou. Yes the File is saved as echoed Response from php script as UTF-8 File. Access Function send a request to the php file which gives back the result "rendered" in INI-File style which i can easily open via "GetINIValue" and send them into my database. I open up a recordset, say that i want my field "product_name" should be filled by GetINIValue("product_details","product_name","filename.ini"). That worked for german and english but not for cyrillic characters. I must save them at first into my database before i show them on screen.

Comment: I edited my post and added the source with the method of which I've tested @Remou, unfortunately, does not lead to the result which was being considered. Maybe I'm just a little mistake there. Would be nice if somebody could look at this again. I must have the Cyrillic characters stored in the database. If the data is stored in the database written in cyrilic everything is displayed correctly, so displaying them is not the problem.. What is missing is only just read from the file along with storing the data in the database

Comment: I tested your code exactly as it is written on my PC and I ended up with Cryllic in the database. I am using Windows 7 and Access 2010 in an English language locale.

Comment: Did you test the code i've written down or what you've written before? I'm using Windows 7 64bit with Access 2003 in a German language locale with installed cyrillic language support.

Comment: I've installed cyrillic language support on my working Machine. Will test my own Code again to see if it works or not.

Comment: So i tested the Code again with installed cyrillic language support on my working Machine. First i get back again "??? ????????? ???", looked into the File with Notepad++, saw that encoding was "Little Endian", changed it to UTF-8, now every file i want to read gets back as ??????????????????????????????? in one line

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, i asked this Question and finally got the answer, but because of the lack of time i didn't managed to "Answer myself" here and for other who might have these problems.

**First of all, about the Read-Problem:**

```
The Edit from my Question with TryStateTrue was the Right answer, this was the correct line which was needed to load
```

But now there's the Catch:

**The Rules in VBA(6 or lower) are simple:**

```
What will be saved in an String will be stored as ASCII Value. So every Char which is not an ASCII Code will be thrown away and saved as "?"
```

**How did i managed to save those Data?**

I Managed to save those Data by using an selfwritten Tool in C# (.NET) which can Handle UTF-8 Strings and can Connect to the Database.

- Save Section + Key in List or set as Executable Parameters and where you will "UPDATE" the Value
  e.g.:

  ```
  [product_details]\name;productsTableName;productsNameField;IdentKeyField;IdentKeyValue
  ```
- open Executable with Arguments or without and load the List
- Connect to the desired Access-Database
- Read the Section\Key-Value and Send to the Database directly by UPDATE-STATEMENT
  e.g:

  ```
  "UPDATE [productsTableName] SET [productsNameField]='" + ValueFromSectionKey + "' WHERE [IdentKeyField]=IdentKeyValue
  ```
- Disconnect Database
- Close Program

**The Result:**

- a little bit slower at first because writing down what Huge List of Informations
- also Writing down everything inside the Database, also with Errors (??????  instead of считаю) secures that if your file is ASCII-"readable" you didn't forget anything
- beautiful UTF-8-Encoded and Readable Text inside an Access 2003 Database

**The Pros about this Method**

- outsourced and expendable Tool, when written correctly it can be used for other projects too
- understanable Code in Access (you write down informations, and after everything was listed you open up a Program which process these)
- very fast when optimized (read the Length and split the list into multiple workers which update the database simultanously)

**The Cons about this Method**

- outsourced
- no possibility to save directly into a variable inside VBA(6 or lower)
- external tool could be blocked by firewall
- before "updating" Database there is unreadable Text inside the Database
- more Update-Calls on Database as directly
- user-typos inside list or Text containing the delimiter may let the UPDATE statement fail.

Hope i could help.